# How to add another menu item on magister bootstrap theme?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Seems like mission impossible!! 
only four elements allow me to add!! Idk why :S 
when try to add one more, the icon bar it messes up and i don't know what to do!!

here's my code example

```
<nav class="mainmenu">
<div class="container">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
        <!-- <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown trigger</a> -->
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
            <li><a href="#head" class="active">Hello</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#themes">Themes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Get in touch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#example">example</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

i just added an last item in menu! and next when i run it and want to expand the menu, impossible !! please help!! why??! also tried to fill the elements #contact #example, creating a submenu on index 
example

```
<section class="section" id="example"></section>
```

still a real mess! the menu won't open

this is the template
http://www.bootstrapstage.com/magister/

Answer (score 0):

found it seeing the code as a amateur :P

so in the assets/csss/magister.css

find the line

```
.mainmenu .dropdown-menu {
top: -14em;
```

and set top to

```
top: -114em;
```

this will solve all the dilemma and sh*t